# HAProxy only allow url with specific suffix

Tags: haproxy

Is there a way to allow only URLs in a given format in haproxy?
I would like to allow connections only if the address contains a specific suffix (in my case .png or .jpg or .gif) and reject it with a 404 if not.

Does Haproxy allows regexp?

like:

```
(myurl).*\.(png|jpg|gif)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a test of `path_reg`.

```
http-request deny unless { path_reg \.(png|jpg|gif)$ }
```

Or, simply with literal string matches in a named ACL.   If any rule in a named ACL matches, the ACL matches.

```
acl path_ok path_end .gif
acl path_ok path_end .jpg
acl path_ok path_end .png
http-request deny unless path_ok
```